# Listview item empty at first but when you scroll out and in, it shows the content

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a `ListView` and `BaseAdapter` and its list items are created dynamically. However, there is an issue.

At first, list item appears very long and empty, but when you scroll down until it is out of screen, then scroll it back on screen, it is visible without problems. What is the issue here?

```
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(activity);
                        tableLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                        tableLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                        JSONObject table = new JSONObject(inputs.getJSONObject(i).getString("Data"));
                        int rowCount = table.getJSONArray("Rows").length();
                        int columnCount = table.getJSONArray("Rows").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("Column").length();
                        String tableData[][] = new String[rowCount][columnCount];

                        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {

                            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(activity);
                            TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            tableRow.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                            if(row%2==1){ tableRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY); }


                            for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; column++) {
                                tableData[row][column] = table.getJSONArray("Rows").getJSONObject(row).getJSONArray("Column").getString(column);

                                TextView tableItem = new TextView(activity);
                                tableItem.setText(table.getJSONArray("Rows").getJSONObject(row).getJSONArray("Column").getString(column));
                                if(columnCount>1){
                                    tableItem.setMaxWidth(holder.innerLinearLayout.getWidth()/columnCount-1);
                                }
                                tableItem.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                                tableItem.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                                tableItem.setPadding(8, 0, 8, 0);
                                if (row == 0) tableItem.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                tableRow.addView(tableItem);
                            }

                            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

                        }

                        holder.innerLinearLayout.addView(tableLayout);
```

Edit:

```
tableItem.setMaxWidth(holder.innerLinearLayout.getWidth()/columnCount-1);
```

This is the line causing the issue, when I remove it the height is fixed too, but table item widths are broken.

Comment: Please, edit your question, post the Adapter (mostly likely the issue here), the `getCount()`, `newView()` and `bindView()`

Comment: @Jdodo please post adapter

Comment: Added the problem part.

Answer (score 0):

I thing the problem is that the `holder.innerLinearLayout`'s width is 0 until the first layout pass. When you scroll back the view are reused, so they have a width.

If you want the columns to have the same width, a possible solution is to set them stretchable with an initial width of 0.

```
tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);

....

// use TableLayout.LayoutParams on TableLayout's children
TableLayout.LayoutParams rowLayoutParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
tableRow.setLayoutParams(rowLayoutParams);

...

/// TableRow.LayoutParams on TableRow's children
/// with a 0 initial width
TableRow.LayoutParams itemLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tableItem.setLayoutParams(itemLayoutParams);
```